# Why is my UIView that I add programmatically not connected to my UIViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uialertview

I'm trying to develop a custom alert view controller in Swift. I made a `UIViewController` in my storyboard for my AlertViewController. Then, when I need to show it, I do the following : I add a subView to my original view which is as big as the original view and creates the opaque background. I then add a second subView to that view to show my `AlertViewController.view`. The following is the code I use to show my AlertView :

```
let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("topicAlertView") as! EditTopicAlertViewController
let alertView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height))

alertView.backgroundColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 23/255.0, green: 62/255.0, blue: 67/255.0, alpha: 0.75)

let alertBox = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: alertView.bounds.size.width / 2.0 - 150.0, y: alertView.bounds.size.height / 2.0 - 100.0, width: 300, height: 200))


alertBox.addSubview(vc.view)
alertView.addSubview(alertBox)
```

That works and correctly shows my alert view. However, it seems like if it's not connected at all to its `UIViewController` : "**EditTopicAlertViewController**" . For example I have a cancel button with a action connected to it and that it's not called at all, nor I can add a

```
vc.cancelButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(EditTopicAlertViewController.cancelPressed(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

Because vc.cancelButton returns `nil`.

If you have any idea how could I fix this, that'd be really appreciated if you could let me know! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please read "Implementing a Container View Controller" in the docs for `UIViewController`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I add the view I also need to add the viewController itself, with the following :

```
self.addChildViewController(vc)
```

Then, when I want to remove it I add the following line to the "followingPressed" method :

```
self.removeFromParentViewController()
```

Comment: Well done. You found the answer yourself. (voted.) Was rmaddy's comment helpful?